# HTML not being rendered in email

Tags: php, html

```
$message = 'What are the other benefits to saying "nah" that you can think of? - ' . $_POST['other-benefits'] . '<br>' .
       'What are you pledging to do? - ' . $_POST['what-pledge'] . '</p>';
```

I am trying to do a break after each line in php but with embedded HTML.  When I send an email(function not included) it doesn't render with breaks.  It literally just types out the 
 as a string.  Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) - Not enough code to support the question.

Comment: "__I send an email, function not included__" the most important part...

Comment: Its just rendering it wrong which is the code I provided.  the mail function works properly.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything,

Comment: ... and yet rendering is usually controlled by email headers, which is part of the function call. Please show more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the lack of information given about the problem, I can only assume that the issue is that the headers of the email have not been set to send HTML emails.

You'll have to do something along the lines of:

```
// Setup email content.
$to = "example@email.com";
$subject = "Example HTML email";

$message = 'What are the other benefits to saying "nah" that you can think of? - ' . $_POST['other-benefits'] . '<br>' .
       'What are you pledging to do? - ' . $_POST['what-pledge'] . '</p>';

// Setup headers.
$headers = "From: from@email.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: replyto@email.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

// This next one is where the magic happens.
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

// Send!
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Refer to: https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 2):

In order to send an email containing html, pay special attention to the following headers:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

---

Example Code:

```
$otherbenefits = $_POST['other-benefits'];
$whatpledge = $_POST['what-pledge'];

$email = <<< LOL
<html> 
  <body> 
    <p> What are the other benefits to saying "nah" that you can think of? - $otherbenefits <br>  What are you pledging to do? - $whatpledge </p>
  </body>
</html>
LOL;

$emailaddress = "personsemail@website.com";
$subject = "Test Email";
$headers = "From: noreply@server.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


mail($emailaddress, $subject, $email, $headers);
```

---

For more information, please visit PHP.net regarding the `mail()` function and how to send email as HTML.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Can you please  comment the down-vote ? this is the code I'm using to send emails containing html and it works as expected.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I know the feeling. The ones with "jam" will.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for the edit, it's always useful the link to the function wiht problems.